# How to group submodule repos in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I've got projects which are dependent on several (20+) submodules.

The projects and submodules are stored in my Gitlab account but the high number of submodules makes my account's project page confusing and long.

I'd like to create a 'group' repository to store all submodules.
Can I do this in Gitlab without losing the dependency links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant documentation is [Redirects when changing repository paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/index.html#redirects-when-changing-repository-paths) (after "[Transferring an existing project into another namespace](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/index.html#transferring-an-existing-project-into-another-namespace)", in your case, a group)

Your .gitmodules (which list and references the submodules with their old URL) should still work, considering

> - Existing web URLs for the namespace and anything under it (e.g., projects) will redirect to the new URLs.
> - The redirects will be available as long as the original path is not claimed by another group, user or project.